# ActionError message not getting displayed in UI

Tags: java, jsp, validation, struts, struts-1

The application is made on Struts 1.2. I have a login form, all the validations related to the login are getting displayed properly. For the validations, I am using the Validator framework.

When the validation succeeds but the user authentication fails, then I am not able to display the login failure message properly.

I am setting the `ActionError` message in the Action like this:

```
Login loginDetails = validateUser(loginForm);
if(loginDetails == null){
    errors.add(ActionErrors.GLOBAL_ERROR, new ActionError("error.invalidCredentials"));
    return mapping.findForward("failure");
}
```

Below is the entry made in the `ApplicationResources.properties` file:

```
error.invalidCredentials=User Name and Password does not match.
```

When the `loginDetails` is null then the errors are getting added properly (I verified this by debugging the code). But the messages are not getting displayed in the UI.

This is what I added in the UI:

```
<td align="right">
    <div style="color:red">
        <html:errors />
    </div>
</td>
```

Below is the entry made in struts-config file:

```
<action input="/mediaLogin.jsp" path="/welcome" type="com.media.action.LoginAction"
    name="loginForm" scope="session" validate="true">
    <forward name="success" path="/rentLibrary.jsp"></forward>
    <forward name="failure" path="/mediaLogin.jsp" redirect="false"></forward>
</action>
```

For an authentication failure, I have given the path as the same page having the login screen and made the `redirect` to `false`.

Please let me know what am I missing :)

**EDIT**

**Full code:**

```
LoginForm loginForm = (LoginForm)form;
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
ActionErrors errors=new ActionErrors();     
if(loginForm.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("Login")){
    // Provide the NUll Check
    Login loginDetails = validateUser(loginForm);
    if(loginDetails == null){
        errors.add(ActionErrors.GLOBAL_ERROR, new ActionError("error.invalidCredentials"));
        return mapping.findForward("failure");
    }
    populateLoginDetails(loginDetails, loginForm);
}
System.out.println("**************************************" + mapping.getAttribute() + "**************************************");
session.setAttribute("userDetails", loginForm);
return mapping.findForward("success");
```

**`Struts-Config.xml`:**

```
<form-beans>    
    <form-bean name="loginForm" type="com.media.form.LoginForm" ></form-bean>   
</form-beans>
<action-mappings>
    <action input="/mediaLogin.jsp" path="/welcome" type="com.media.action.LoginAction"
        name="loginForm" scope="session" validate="true">
        <forward name="success" path="/rentLibrary.jsp"></forward>
        <forward name="failure" path="/mediaLogin.jsp" redirect="false"></forward>
    </action>               
</action-mappings>

<message-resources parameter="resources.ApplicationResources" />

<plug-in className="org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn">
    <set-property property="pathnames"
        value="/WEB-INF/validator-rules.xml,/WEB-INF/validation.xml" />
</plug-in>
```

Comment: Do you get any error in the command line? If yes, put the stack trace.

Comment: NO, I did not get any error...any pointers?

Comment: Refering to the properties file means? I have not done anything like refering to the propertiesfile anywhere other than the `ActionError` parameter. May be this is the mistake...can you please post what else shall I do apart from whatever I posted above? btw, I have added the first full code...let me know if you want any other info.

Comment: Post the whole struts-config file

Comment: pls chk and let me know...apart from tht i have only the form-beans added

Comment: I want to see the form-beans tag as well. So I told you to post the whole file!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error messages not getting displayed, right because you not getting them from the validator form. Struts use `ValidatorForm` that your form should extend and override the `validate` method. In the `validate` method you can check the form fields manually or using Apache commons validator. `GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull` for example checks for fields are required. Fill the `ActionErrors` and call the `super.validate` to get additional errors from the framework that you can merge. Once you call `super.validate` the `ERROR_KEY` is already put into request. Additionally in the post [problem in error handling using struts validator framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4671213/573032)  I've described how handle exceptions during validation to put `EXCEPTION_KEY` to the `error` attribute. Other things like skip validation in the actions and validation dispatch methods possible due to overriding `RequestProcessor` adding validation method keys (Validation Method Key is the key used to map the method used by `getKeyMethodMap()`), and handle the `processValidation`.

```java
ActionErrors actionErrors = super.validate(mapping, request);    
actionErrors.add(ActionErrors.GLOBAL_MESSAGE, new ActionMessage("error.invalidCredentials"));
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to ignore the validation framework and do validate manually in the action

```java
ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();
errors.add(ActionErrors.GLOBAL_MESSAGE, new ActionMessage("error.invalidCredentials"));
request.setAttribute(Globals.ERROR_KEY, errors);
return mapping.findForward("failure");
```

After that it will be possible to display it in JSP via `<html:messages`.

```jsp
<logic:messagesPresent>
  <html:messages id="error">
    <span><bean:write name="error"/></span><br/>
  </html:messages>
</logic:messagesPresent>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I have not added any validate method in theform. Reason: I am fetching the values from the DB for the username and password, checking if user is authenticated or not. All these fetching and authentication check are there in my Action. Hence I have not added any validate method in the Form. Please let me know how to make the above code work in this scenario where the action performs the validation. In the above code, `validateUser` method contains the code for hitting the DB and fetching the values. Please rpely

Comment: @user182944 then you have to do it manually using implementation code for `ValidatorForm.validate` from the framework that used commons validator.

Comment: any sample code for the same? Don't have any idea what you suggested :( Again, am i going the complicated way? Is there some simple way to get this? Please let me know about this :(

Comment: I think you are, because you ignore the validation framework that means you should override forms validate method.

Comment: @user182944 Edited and made complete.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot...that worked finally. Please let me know how to achieve the same using the validations framework. I thought like in validations framework, this is not feasible hence thought of doing think way but my mistake. Another thing is: Please let me know what is the easiest way to do this kind of validations i.e. in the Action...Desperately waiting for your reply...you may edit the above post if the answer is a big one (may be some sample codes) Thanks a lot again for the help.

Comment: What do do you want to get how to use Apache commons validator to ckeck field values or how to extend ValidatorForm and move the validation logic to the validate method?

Comment: My concern is:  how to do the validation in the validate method rather than doing it in the action in this scenario? Reason: I am checking the user authentication by doing a DB hit only which is done in the Action. Only if it fails in the Action, I want to display it in the UI. Please let me know in this scenario, how can I invoke the validate method of the form from Action OR how to pass the validation failure from the Action to the FOrm and display it in the UI OR you want me to do the DB hit in the form validation method itself?

Comment: The `validate` method start before the action and if the action errors are not empty it dispatches to input without action execute. Thus you have to check it there your user.

Comment: You should do validation in the `validate`, you have supplied with mapping and request, but without response, so you cannot dispatch right from there unless you put response into request attribute. But you can keep framework's `ActionErrors` empty during validation and return to the action where you can proceed with forwards.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, add a blank validate() method even if you don't write the code in it as suggested by @RomanC.

Then, try adding

```
saveErrors(request, errors);
```

after

```
errors.add(ActionErrors.GLOBAL_ERROR, new ActionError("error.invalidCredentials"));
```

If this does not work, reply back. Let us make it work first, and then you better use the standard way as @RomanC suggests.

Comment: Hi, This one worked. Can you please let me know what was incorrect in what I did and why do i need to have the dummy validate method added in the Form? Also let me know what is the best way to achieve this (what is the standard way i dont know also :( )....This thread has gone for long, i would love to close it :) Again, thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Struts 1 needs a validate method which is dependency when validate=true is set. Also, the validation is supposed to be in the validate() method instead of the the action. This issue is resolved in Struts 2 where you have the validaters totally separated from the action code. Its better to switch to Struts 2 now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. how to do the validation in the validate method rather than doing it in the action in this scenario??? This is the place where my concern is. Reason: I am checking the user authentication by doing a DB hit only which is done in the Action. Only if it fails in the Action, I want to display it in the UI. Please let me know in this scenario, how can I invoke the validate method of the form from Action OR how to pass the validation failure from the Action to the FOrm and display it in the UI OR you want me to do the DB hit in the form validation method itself :(

Comment: What you are talking about is authentication, not validation. validate() method should not do authentication, it is supposed to do the validation of all the data entered in correct format. Authentication can be done in the action

Comment: Bingo!!! Thats the point. After authentication (or any business side validation such as fetching some data from the DB and then validating the same against some business rules), if its a failure then how to display the message in the UI to the user? Please let me know about this. Sorry for making things confusing but i am confused myself as of now :( Please let me know about this

Comment: If you are talking about populating some data into a combo box from a DB table for example, and then using it for validation, then you have to do it in the validate() method itself. That's the whole point of using Struts 2!! Start learning Struts 2 and you'll understand what I mean..