# Form validation error handling in Struts 1.3 after submit the form with Ajax call

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, validation, struts-1

The environment is Struts 1.3 and jQuery and I have a request of Ajax to retrieve JSON data when submit a form. Everything works fine except for the form validation.

The problem is that the Ajax `dataType` is set to JSON but the return format of validation is not JSON. So, I get parser error in `fail()` method.

Is there a way to get the returned validation messages if the `textStatus` is parser error in the `fail()`? Or any other suggestions to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

As far as you stay on the same page when doing Ajax call you could always return a status with response, and messages after doing it as a `success` callback, or `fail`.

You have also to turn validation framework off and use [commons validator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/) utils to perform validations by hands.

Comment: They want to keep the validation as is. So, I am unable to change the validation to the other way. But, jquery ajax has already received the validation messages. Can I get the messages from anywhere ?

Comment: No, you can't unless you override the request processor, like I did couple of years ago. Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480631/actionerror-message-not-getting-displayed-in-ui/14482782#14482782).